# Searching for items in list

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to search within a list of items (specifically, a list of files from a folder) for certain files. However, I don't know the names of these files; all I know is that they all begin with the same word (for example, "Work 1", "Work 2" and "Work 3"). I tried this script:

```
tell application "Finder"

    set filelist to name of every item in folder (path to desktop)

    set endlist to {}

    repeat with i from 1 to count filelist
    if {filelist's item i}'s name begins with "Work" then set endlist's end to filelist's item i

    end repeat
end tell
```

which at first glance would seem about right, but whenevr I run it I get error number -1728 from name. (error "Can’t get name of {\"file1\"}." number -1728 from name of {"file1.txt"}) (this "File1" happens to be the first item in the "filelist" list)

I know that applescript can recognize if an item in the list starts with "work", since this:

```
 if ((some item whose name begins with "Work") exists) then...
```

works fine, so I'm not sure what to do next...

P.S. just in case, I've tried many iterations of the "If" statemente in the script, including

```
  if name of {filelist's item i} begins with "Work" then...
```

and none have worked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It a simple problem to solve.

You are first asking for the names of every item.

```
set filelist to name of every item in folder (path to desktop)
```

Which returns a list of the names. ***As text items***.

Then you want to  do your search. But in your code you are asking for the **name** of the text item.

Thats why you are getting the error. The text item does not have a name.

Change the line:

```
if {filelist's item i}'s name begins with "Work" then set endlist's end to filelist's item i
```

to

```
if filelist's item i begins with "Work" then set endlist's end to filelist's item i
```

UPDATE: 
In response to your comment.

You can create a list of the names of the items found on the desktop whose name  begins with for example "Work"

Doing it this way may be better.

Here you ask for a list containing the *names*  of any item found whose **name** (returned as a text item text) begins with ..

```
tell application "Finder"

    set filelist to name of every item in folder (path to desktop) whose name begins with "Work"
end tell
```